# Example of convergence in probability to a non-degenerate rv

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose the sequence of random variables, X$_n$, converges in probability to another random variable X. The condition requires that for any arbitrary distance, $\epsilon$, the probability that the X$_n$ can be further than $\epsilon$ from X eventually goes to zero.

Although one can think of many examples where the random variable X is a degenerate rv (i.e. a constant), is there an example of where X is not? If we suppose X is a non-degenerate rv that has some distribution as do the X$_n$, it is hard for me to see an example of where the probability that the X$_n$ would eventually have to be within any arbitrary distance from X could be made to go to zero (considering that the rv X itself has dispersion). Sorry, I'm not saying this very well, as I am a student, but my textbook and the others I've consulted, give no such examples.

Thank you,

Matt

Comment: $X_n = Z + 1/n$, $X = Z$ ?

Comment: Don't assume Xn and X are independent!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a bare-bones linear regression model

$$y_i = bx_i + u_i$$

Now consider the **i**-th *residual* from ordinary least-squares estimation,

$$\hat u_i = y-\hat b_nx_i = (b-\hat b_n)x_i + u_i $$

Under the standard assumptions for this model, $\hat b_n$, which is a random variable that depends on all $x_i$'s and all $u_i$'s, is consistent for $b$ i.e. it converges in probability to $b$. So

$$\text{plim}_{n\rightarrow \infty} \hat u_i = \text{plim}_{n\rightarrow \infty} \big[(b-\hat b_n)x_i + u_i \big] =u_i$$

The residual, which is a random variable, converges to the true error, which is also a random variable.